# Properly doing imports to avoid conflicting modules

Tags: python

I've written a few tools to run inside a python environment, specifically Autodesk Maya (A 3d animation package software). Generally i like to build my tools with the same folder structure as scene below.

I was wondring, how would i properly write my 'import' statements in the utils/general.py file if i wanted it to import views/objects.py without conflicting and trying to import from the wrong tool?

```
ToolA
    - views/
        objects.py
    - utils/
        general.py
    main.py


ToolB
    - views/
        objects.py
    - utils/
        general.py
    main.py
```

Comment: One could use relative imports -- something like `from ..views import objects`

Comment: Does that avoid the python environment from importing from the wrong location?

Comment: When executing the general.py file with this `from .models import models` i get the following error `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the package/module concepts for Python. Specifically, adding `__init__.py` files may help your imports.

See this answer for somewhere to get started:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/3856731